# ¿Cómo pasar valor de una variable a otra variable?

Tags: php, variables

Quiero pasar un valor de una variable a otra variable en el mismo documento PHP

Estoy queriendo pasar el valor más ya el formateado a la variable $pay de la siguiente manera:

```
number_format($pago,1) = $pay;

echo "$pay";
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\variables\index.php on line 35

**Línea 15**

```
echo "$pay";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trata esto,

```
$pay = number_format($pago,2,',''.');

echo $pay;
```

espero que te funcione

Comment: Estupendo gracias :)