# error en php, :Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, string, funciones

tengo una función en php, que recibe unos parámetros para generar un string, y me da ese error.
La función recibe cadenas y números
**Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context.**
esta es la funcion:

```
function generar_cadena( $nombre, $apellido, $genero, $cabecera, $dia_nac, $mes_nac, $anio_nac){

        // quitar caracteres especiales de nombres y apellidos
            $nombre2 = str_replace(
            array('á','é','í','ó','ú','Á','É','Í','Ó','Ú','Ñ','ñ'),
            array('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U','N','n'),$nombre );
            $apellido2 = str_replace(
            array('á','é','í','ó','ú','Á','É','Í','Ó','Ú','Ñ','ñ'),
            array('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U','N','n'),$apellido );

        // separo los primeros 3 caracteres del primer nombre y 1 del segundo
            $name = explode(" ", $nombre2);
            $name1 = substr($name[0],0, 3);
            if (isset($name[1])) {
                $name2 =substr($name[1],0,  1);
            }else{
                 $name2 = null;
            }
           
        // separo los primeros 3 caracteres del primer apellido y 1 del segundo
            $last_name = explode(" ", $apellido2);
            $last_name1 = substr($last_name[0],0,  3);
            if (isset($last_name[1])) {
                    $last_name2 =substr($last_name[1],0,  1);
            }else{
                 $last_name2 = null;
            }

        // trabajo la fecha de nacimiento por separado
            //dia
            if ($dia_nac <=9  && strlen($dia_nac) = 1) {
                    $dia_nac =  "0".$dia_nac;
            }else{
                $dia_nac =  $nino[6];
            }
            // mes 
            if ($mes_nac <=9  && strlen($mes_nac) = 1) {
                    $mes_nac =  "0".$mes_nac;
            }else{
                $mes_nac =  $mes_nac;
            }
            
            // año
            $anio_nac =  $anio_nac;


        //id 
        $cadena =  $cabecera.$genero.strtoupper($name1).strtoupper($name2).strtoupper($last_name1).strtoupper($last_name2).$anio_nac.$mes_nac.$dia_nac;

         return $cadena;
}
```

**Aqui hago la llamada de la función lo que me arroja el error fatal:**
`$cadena = generar_cadena( $nombre, $apellido, $genero, $cabecera, $dia_nac, $mes_nac, $anio_nac) ;`

** Si alguien pudiese guiarme, ayudarme le agradezco de antemano**

Comment: Esto ya se preguntó [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110909/c%c3%b3mo-pasar-valor-de-una-variable-a-otra-variable) y el error se debe a que las comparaciones deben hacerse con (al menos) doble signo igual, si se hace con solo uno, se trata de asignación. Tu error: `if ($dia_nac <=9  && strlen($dia_nac) = 1)`, que debería ser: `if ($dia_nac <=9  && strlen($dia_nac) == 1)`

Comment: Si, justo lo acabo de corregir. Gracias.

Comment: También te recomiendo usar la función `normalize()` de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/376066/54039) para remplazar caracteres con tilde.